# XML from URL into historical data graph

Tags: php, mysql, graph

What I'm after is a service or script that pulls XML from a URL once every x minutes, saves the data to a mysql database and then users are able to search for an item and it displays historical price data for that item.

This is what the XML looks like for 1 item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Success>
   <Result>
      <AccId>2075</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>100</Price>
      <SaleId>211557</SaleId>
      <Time>636662891054273275</Time>
      <Hours>47</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>7911</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>100</Price>
      <SaleId>198528</SaleId>
      <Time>636662291658957640</Time>
      <Hours>31</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>8839</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>110</Price>
      <SaleId>203789</SaleId>
      <Time>636662477761119929</Time>
      <Hours>36</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9897</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>211261</SaleId>
      <Time>636662870212977640</Time>
      <Hours>47</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9897</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>211445</SaleId>
      <Time>636662885517249200</Time>
      <Hours>47</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9897</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>211396</SaleId>
      <Time>636662880277082389</Time>
      <Hours>47</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9897</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>211399</SaleId>
      <Time>636662880277106287</Time>
      <Hours>47</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9897</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>211259</SaleId>
      <Time>636662870086140573</Time>
      <Hours>47</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9897</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>211400</SaleId>
      <Time>636662880279095669</Time>
      <Hours>47</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9897</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>211257</SaleId>
      <Time>636662870086133672</Time>
      <Hours>47</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9897</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>211256</SaleId>
      <Time>636662870086130216</Time>
      <Hours>47</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9897</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>211388</SaleId>
      <Time>636662879775606621</Time>
      <Hours>47</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9897</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>211389</SaleId>
      <Time>636662879775618280</Time>
      <Hours>47</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>8839</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>189990</SaleId>
      <Time>636661845264224374</Time>
      <Hours>18</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>1570</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>185279</SaleId>
      <Time>636661608303483850</Time>
      <Hours>12</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>6144</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>193953</SaleId>
      <Time>636662075376965802</Time>
      <Hours>25</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>6867</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>120</Price>
      <SaleId>210396</SaleId>
      <Time>636662809913772219</Time>
      <Hours>45</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>10091</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>150</Price>
      <SaleId>209347</SaleId>
      <Time>636662744031038414</Time>
      <Hours>43</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9326</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>150</Price>
      <SaleId>192933</SaleId>
      <Time>636662020656105309</Time>
      <Hours>23</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>9326</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>150</Price>
      <SaleId>192934</SaleId>
      <Time>636662020656108191</Time>
      <Hours>23</Hours>
   </Result>
   <Result>
      <AccId>5979</AccId>
      <Type>2793</Type>
      <Price>150</Price>
      <SaleId>190952</SaleId>
      <Time>636661905157273715</Time>
      <Hours>20</Hours>
   </Result>
   <TotalAuctions>4114</TotalAuctions>
</Success>
```

I need it to calculate the High, Low and Average of all the  and add it to the database and the graph will be based off that with history

Comment: Would you please show us what you have tried so far? Otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have found highcharts.com, I will give it a go